# Create samples that are the same when unordered, but have some specific correlation when ordered

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

I have 100,000 random samples (with replacement) X_i from an otherwise unknown distribution.

I want to create a series Y_i that

1. is the same as X_i except for the ordering and
2. gives a correlation between X and Y of some given number (or a correlation close to that given number).

Is there a known technique/procedure/algorithm for this?

Comment: 1) Correlation here means Pearson correlation?
$\tag*{}$
2) You are aware that the range of possible correlations depends on the marginal distribution? And "some given number" here means "some given attainable number"?

Comment: @gg Yes. Not sure how this is relevant. Yes (or a number close to that). As an example: if I have X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 28, 2, 4], I want to find a Y consisting of the same numbers but in a different order that gives me a correlation between X and Y of 0.8.

Comment: I doubt a correlation of $0.8$ is possible in your example: `Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 28, 6, 2, 4]` seems to give a correlation less than $0.14$ while `Y = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 28, 4, 2]` seems to give a correlation greater than $0.93$

Comment: With a less extreme example (the $28$ is the killer) just take many permutations of parts (varying lengths) of the original sequence and choose the one closest to your target correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a quick and dirty solution which may or may not be appropriate in your situation. In what follows $N$ is the sample size.

1. Create a bivariate normal sample of size $N$ with the desired correlation. $(Z_1, Z_2)$
2. Register the relative ranks (or order statistics) of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ this provides you with a bivariate Vektor of ranks $(U_1, U_2).$
3. Register the ranks of your sample $X$.
4. Create $Y$ by choosing from $X$ so that the ranks of $(X,Y)$ are the same as $(U_1, U_2).$

For various reasons the procedure is not (and cannot be) exact, but in many cases it should work quite well and is easy to implement.

Comment: Nice! I think that would work in my situation.